# Same Quartz.Net scheduler in multiple app server.

Tags: c#, scheduler, quartz.net

im the new in Quartz.NET (v.3.0.3).I have console application and it's quartz host and broadcasting ***tcp.x:555/QuartzScheduler***.

In my company we have 2 app server machines and they're master-slave themselves.If master app is down slave take it's place.We will setup console application ( as a service ) in these servers.

If we do that what happens in Quartz.NET , is these schedulers will be same or different ?

PS: we're using MsSQL jobStore (AdoNetJobStore).

Thank you for reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my own solution in this page ;

[Quartz.NET Clustering](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering)

I duplicate my console app and change port address (1 : localhost:555 port , 2 : localhost:556 port ) , create six jobs three of them run in 30 sec , others run in 60 sec.we run them in same time and here what quartz do ;

[running same PC Console App](https://i.hizliresim.com/8Yo4Jn.png)

and my properies ;

```
<quartz>
    <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value="RemoteServer"></add>
    <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceId" value="AUTO"></add>
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.clustered" value="true"></add>
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz"></add>
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value="5"></add>
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadPriority" value="Normal"></add>

    <!-- Tcp Hosting-->
    <add key="quartz.scheduler.exporter.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.RemotingSchedulerExporter, Quartz"></add>
    <add key="quartz.scheduler.exporter.port" value="556"></add>
    <add key="quartz.scheduler.exporter.bindName" value="QuartzScheduler"></add>
    <add key="quartz.scheduler.exporter.channelType" value="tcp"></add>
    <add key="quartz.scheduler.exporter.channelName" value="httpQuartz"></add>

    <!-- DB-->
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.type" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz"></add>
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.useProperties" value="true"></add>
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.dataSource" value="myDS"></add>
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix" value="[dbo].QRTZ_"></add>
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SqlServerDelegate, Quartz"></add>
    <add key="quartz.dataSource.myDS.connectionString" value="Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx"></add>
    <add key="quartz.dataSource.myDS.provider" value="SqlServer"></add>
    <add key="quartz.serializer.type" value="binary"></add>
```

Thank you !