# Communicating quartz application with another quartz in another machine

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

I am new at Quartz Job scheduler . I want to schedule a job from another machine (Linux,Windows ..), it will be running on web logic , because that machine has no eclipse . We need to run this for different job agents

I am looking for helpful links  and examples to achieve this feature .

Answer (score 0):

check this out (Its for .NET) ;

[Ours job machines.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49175092/same-quartz-net-scheduler-in-multiple-app-server)

We have double app machine and they're running bot scheduler with different ports and same database( mssql ) and Quartz have load balance mechanism.

Thank you !